# finding and sorting datapoints in bash and awk

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot

First of all, let me clarify that I am unfortunately still quite inexperienced in programming, so I really need some help.

**What I have:**

I have a data file containing 3 columns: `$1=(Energy1)`, `$2=(Energy2)`, `$3=(intensity of their frequency in combination)`. 
If I plot these data e.g. in gnuplot by doing `spl "datafile.dat" u 1:2:3` I obtain a surface plot with my 2D-spectrum.

**What I want:**

Now, I would like to select only certain data points, for which my `($1-$2)=5.7` give this specific value, thus obtaining a line spectrum along a diagonal, with all possible combinations of `$1` and `$2` yielding this value.

The new data-file should then contain the `$1`-value and the intensity (stored in `$3`) corresponding to the selected line, which contained the correct values of `$1` and `$2` yielding 5.7.

I have tried do do this in bash using awk, but unfortunately until now I failed. PLEASE help me!!! thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It would help us if you provided a small sample of your input data, along with the desired output data.

Comment: You can surely do this with awk but the value 5.7 could lead to some issues if you test for an equality (because 5.7 can't be exactly encoded as a float number; it would be better to check for values close to it rather than for exact matches).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `awk` for this, `gnuplot` can do it.

```
admissible(x,y,value,epsilon)=(abs(x-y-value)<epsilon)
plot 'datafile.dat' using (admissible($1,$2,5.7,1e-5)?$1:1/0):3 with points
```

Function `admissible` is tested for each line of data file, if it returns true then the point ($1,$3) is plotted, else the x-coordinate is set to undefined (1/0) and thus the point is not plotted. The only shortcoming is that you cannot use the `lines` style with this, since lines will be interrupted by non-admissible datapoints.

Comment: No, `set table` alone doesn't help for plotting with lines since also the invalid points are written to the output files

Comment: @Christoph True--one has to exclude the lines ending in "u" with another tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand all the issues, or maybe you are having a floating-equal problem as others have noted, but why doesn't a simple filter through the data work?:

```
awk -v s=5.7 -v e=.01 '{d=$1-$2-$s}d<e&&d>-e{print $1,$3}'
```

Tack on a sort if you want/need:

```
| sort -n
```

Or, is it possible that your data is too sparse, and you're looking for some value interpolation solution?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very useful. I tried the "gnuplot"-command already mentioned below, but to store the values I need "awk" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare every $1 against every $2, you need to take 2 passes through the file, once to collect all the $1,$3 pairs, the next to do all the comparisons:

```
awk -v diff=5.7 '
    NR == FNR {
        # this is the first trip through
        val[$1] = $3
        next
    }
    {
        for (v1 in val) {
            if ( (v1 - $2) == diff ) {
                print v1, val[v1]
            }
        }
    }
' file file   # yes, give the same filename twice.
```

To address @Baruchel's comment about floating point precision, try this:

```
awk -v diff=5.7 -v epsilon=0.0001'
    NR == FNR {val[$1] = $3; next}
    {
        for (v1 in val) {
            delta = v1 - $2 - diff
            if (-epsilon <= delta && delta <= epsilon) 
                print v1, val[v1]
        }
    }
' file file
```